# Laravel Eloquent Where json cell

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My table has a json encoded column called `skills` and I have to check if any value exist in another array `$skillArray` in a eloquent query. How can I achieve this?

```
Employee::whereIn('skills', $skillArray);
```

`skills` has values like `"["1","2","15"]"` (string) (in DB) 
`$skillArray` is `[9,4]` (array) 
Attribute casting not preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use [JSON column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) / [JSON column queries](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses) or a many-to-many relationship table, you would have to use a regular expression WHERE clause:

```php
$regex = '"(' . implode('|', $skillArray) . ')"';
Employee::where('skills', 'REGEXP', $regex);
```

This will assume:

- The `skills` column is a string of a JSON array with IDs
- `$skillArray` is always an array with IDs
- Left and right of the number is a `"`.
- Also: Numbers in `$skillArray` may be in any order

Comment: Hello, thank you for the replay. I noticed that in the DB, `skills` have quotes, i.e. its like `skills: "["1","2","15"]"`. I tried your code, I think the quotes is the problem. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: Then I'll add `"` to the regex, easy as that.

Comment: Wow. Never knew this was possible. Worked like a charm.